# how to parse date in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hi guys I'm using angularjs in my project when i'm trying to get to this api:

```
http://localhost:8082/api/position/timeLineSelectedItem/2/2017-03-25 09:32:58/2017-03-25 11:29:43
```

its gives an error:

```
GET http://localhost:8082/api/position/timeLineSelectedItem/2/2017-03-25%2009:32:58/2017-03-25%2011:29:43 400 (Bad Request)
 (anonymous) @ angular.js:11048
 n @ angular.js:10841
 g @ angular.js:10551
 (anonymous) @ angular.js:15122
 $eval @ angular.js:16384
 $digest @ angular.js:16200
 (anonymous) @ angular.js:16423
  e @ angular.js:5764
  (anonymous) @ angular.js:6041
 angular.js:12808 SyntaxError: Unexpected token I in JSON at position 0
at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
at uc (angular.js:1284)
at $b (angular.js:9723)
at angular.js:9814
at p (angular.js:341)
at ed (angular.js:9813)
at c (angular.js:10602)
at angular.js:15122
at n.$eval (angular.js:16384)
at n.$digest (angular.js:16200)
```

so what is the problem.

Comment: `so what is the problem.` <= For starters I see no json in your question at all and there is an error that the json is invalid. For additional help create an [mcve] and read throw [ask] a good question. For now I'm voting to close because you have shown no code at all (client side or server side) so any answer will be pure speculation.

Comment: the problem is in the date which passed on the function

Comment: is it the coerrect way to do that or i have to parse it???

Comment: We can't help you with a JSON parsing error unless you show us the JSON.  I'm also voting to close.  Show us the response to your request.

Comment: possible duplicate 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1859181/how-do-i-pass-a-date-via-the-url-for-my-action-to-read-in-mvc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you see this error, is most likely because your endpoint `http://localhost:8082/api/position/timeLineSelectedItem/2/2017-03-25 09:32:58/2017-03-25 11:29:43` returns as a Bad Request. I'm not sure which web server you're using, but I'm guessing that the body of this Bad Request error response, is some kind of html debug page. Then when Angular tries to parse that as json, it fails (at position 0, since the first character of the response body is probably `<`).

So first, try to find out why your request returns a Bad Request response. It might be caused by the server not being able to parse the date, or it might be something completely different. There's no way we can know it without more information from you.

Then, if the Bad Request response is the expected behavior of your backend, you'll need to change your backend to return error messages in json format, instead of as an html debug page (which I'm assuming is what you're getting).